# Apply Query Builder object to a Database connection in Laravel

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In a Laravel application, I would like to build the query conditions separate to the DB connection. Is this possible to do?

I am hoping for something like a function that will take a request. This function will then use the request data to build the query builder object with the conditions and then return the builder object. Then use that elsewhere with the DB connection. For example:

```php
public function BuildQuery($request)
{
    $query = new Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder();
    // PROCESS REQUEST //
    $query->where('name','John'); // EXAMPLE
    return $query;
}

public function UseQuery($request)
{
    // VALIDATE
    DB::table('table')->query($this->BuildQuery($request));
    // FURTHER CODE
}
```

Is something like this do-able?

EDIT:
This is a Laravel 10 application

Comment: why not pass the builder you just created to the `BuildQuery` method with the Request?